# How can I grep in PDF files?

Tags: grep, search, pdf

Is there a way to search PDF files using grep, without converting to text first in Ubuntu?

Comment: See also [Is there some sort of PDF to text -converter?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4759/is-there-some-sort-of-pdf-to-text-converter) and [Command line tool to search phrases in large number of pdf files](http://superuser.com/questions/163182/command-line-tool-to-search-phrases-in-large-number-of-pdf-files).

Comment: For people comming here via search: If you are willing to convert it first to text files, have a look at [How to search contents of multiple pdf files?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34571215/562769)

Answer (score 304, accepted):

Install the package `pdfgrep`, then use the command:

```
find /path -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep pattern {} +
```

——————

Simplest way to do that:

```
pdfgrep 'pattern' *.pdf
pdfgrep 'pattern' file.pdf
```

Comment: This works in mac osx (Mavericks) as well. Install it using brew. Simple. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity I checked the source of pdfgrep and it uses poppler to extract strings from the pdf. Almost exactly as @wag's answer only pagewise rather than, presumably, the entire document.

Comment: `pdfgrep` also has a recursive flag. So this answer could perhaps be reduced to: `pdfgrep -R pattern /path/`. Though it might be less effective if it goes through every file even if it isn't a PDF. And I notice that it has issues with international characters such as å, ä and ö.

Comment: Actually, the `-n` option is a pro for pdfgrep as it allows to include the page number in the output (might be helpful for further processing).

Comment: This answer would be easier to use if it explained which bits of the command are meant to copied literally and which are placeholders. What's `pattern`? What's `{}`? What's up with the ` +`? I have no idea upon first reading... so off to the manpage I go, I suppose.

Comment: @MarkAmery This answer is unnecessarily complex because he is `find`.  The usage is simply `pdfgrep 'pattern' file.pdf`.  The `{}` is just a way to drop the file name in from `find`.

Comment: As pdfgrep is quite slow, you can increase the speed by using parallel find: `find . -type f -iname \*.pdf -print0 | xargs -0 -P 4 -L 1 pdfgrep -H -n pattern`. That obviously depends on the number of CPUs and available IO.

Comment: see here for examples too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643438/how-to-search-contents-of-multiple-pdf-files

Comment: Recursive search worked on my Debian just with `find`, e.g.: `find . -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep 'wandtank' {} +`

Comment: upon some initial testing doesn't find successfully the files that contain the words.

Comment: It worked excellently on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 85):

If you have `poppler-utils` installed (default on Ubuntu Desktop), you could "convert" it on the fly and pipe it to `grep`:

```
pdftotext my.pdf - | grep 'pattern'
```

This won't create a .txt file.

Comment: so .. you extract the text before you grep it which means the answer is "no".

Comment: @akira The OP probably meant "without opening the PDF in a viewer and exporting to text"

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: then that should be clarified by OP, but "grep only" is pretty clear to me.

Comment: @akira Where do you see "grep only"?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: "the power of grep, without converting the text" is pretty clear. "grep foo *.pdf".

Comment: @akira Well, I already said what I think he probably meant; he doesn't want to export to text before processing it. I very much doubt he has a problem with *any* command that converts to text in any way; there's no reason not to

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: "then that should be clarified by OP".

Comment: Nice solution. What is the purpose of the `-` character preceding the pipe? I observed that without it, or with any or character, the a file is created with the same name and the grep is not executed as expected. Is this how *all* linux piping is done when the intermediate file is unnecessary?

Comment: @sherrellbc The second argument of `pdftotext` is the filename it should write to. However, by convention, tools typically allow you to write to `stdout` instead of to a file by specifying a `-` instead. Similarly, some tools would write to `stdout` by default if you omit such an argument entirely (but this is not always possible without creating ambiguity).

Comment: @Joost what if one wants to pipe `pdftotext` to `find`? I guess `while read` is in order.

Answer (score 33):

[pdfgrep](https://pdfgrep.org) was written for exactly this purpose and is available in Ubuntu.

It tries to be mostly compatible to `grep` and thus provides "the power of grep", only specialized for PDFs. That includes common grep options, such as `--recursive`, `--ignore-case` or `--color`.

In contrast to `pdftotext | grep`, pdfgrep can output the page number of a match in a performant way and is generally faster when it doesn't have to search the whole document (e.g. `--max-count` or `--quiet`).

The basic usage is:

```
pdfgrep PATTERN FILE..
```

where `PATTERN` is your search string and `FILE` a list of filenames (or wildcards in a shell).

See the [manpage](https://pdfgrep.org/doc.html) for more infos.

Comment: As of [release 2.0](https://pdfgrep.org/news/pdfgrep-2.0-released.html) `pdfgrep` has a `--cache` option to drastically speed up multiple searches on the same files.

Answer (score 8):

There is a duplicate question on StackOverflow. The people there suggest a variation of harish.venkarts answer:

```
find /path -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "your pattern"' \;
```

The advantage over the similar answer here is the `--with-filename` flag for grep. This is somewhat superior to pdfgrep as well, because the standard grep has more features.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643438/how-to-search-contents-of-multiple-pdf-files

Comment: I think it would have been better to leave this as a comment (or edit) in the similar answer you are referring to.

Answer (score 7):

No.

A pdf consists of chunks of data, some of them text, some of them pictures and some of them really magical fancy XYZ (eg. .u3d files). Those chunks are most of the times compressed (eg. flat, check http://www.verypdf.com/pdfinfoeditor/compression.htm). In order to 'grep' a .pdf you *have* to reverse the compression aka extract the text.

You can do that either per file with tools such as `pdf2text` and grep the result, or you run an 'indexer' (look at [xapian.org](http://xapian.org) or [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)) which builds an searchable index out of your .pdf files and then you can use the search engine tools of that indexer to get the content of the pdf.

But no, you can not `grep` pdf files and hope for reliable answers without extracting the text first.

Comment: Considering `pdfgrep` exists (see above), a flat "no" is incorrect.

Comment: @JonathanCross, considering the question says "using the power of grep, without converting to text first", a flat "no" *is* correct.

Comment: A good way to ask for an alternative without explicit requesting an alternative. Anyway, lucene as indexer works generally well.

Comment: @JonathanCross The verb **convert** is ambiguous. To insist on one interpretation instead of a possibly different one in the mind of the OP is uncharitable pedantry.

Comment: @JonathanCross :) "use grep without convert to text" is the limiting part of the question. A question like "can I use $something on CLI to search for text in PDFs" would have yielded a different answer from me … or none at all because those `pdftotext` answers exist already.

Answer (score 7):

[Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/features.html) can search PDFs. It doesn't support regular expressions, but it has lots of other search options, so it might fit your needs.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the common resource grep tool [crgrep](https://sourceforge.net/projects/crgrep) which supports searching within PDF files.

It also allows searching other resources like content nested in archives, database tables, image meta-data, POM file dependencies and web resources - and combinations of these including recursive search.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick script for search pdf in the current directory :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "usage $0 VALUE" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

echo 'SEARCH IS CASE SENSITIVE' 1>&2

find . -name '*.pdf' -exec /bin/bash -c 'pdftotext "{}" - | grep --with-filename --label="{}" --color "$0"' "$1" \;
```

Comment: I cannot edit this due to being to little: The `$1` in the find invocation should be quoted, otherwise this won't work with search terms with spaces.

Comment: @ankon fixed it :)

Answer (score 3):

You could pipe it through `strings` first:-

```
cat file.pdf | strings | grep <...etc...>
```

Comment: Just use `strings file.pdf | grep <...>`, you don't need `cat`

Comment: Yeah - my mind seems to work better with streams... :-)

Comment: wont work if text is compressed, which it is most of the times.

Comment: Even if the text is uncompressed, it's generally small pieces of sentences (not even necessarily whole words!) finely intermixed with formatting information.  Not very friendly for `strings` or `grep`.

Comment: Can you think of another reason why using strings for this wouldn't work?  I found that using strings works on some PDFs but not others.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
find /path -iname *.pdf -print0 | for i in `xargs 0`; do echo $i; \
    pdftotext "$i" - | grep pattern; done
```

for printing the lines the pattern occurs inside the pdf

Answer (score 2):

cd to your folder containing your pdf-file and then..

```
pdfgrep 'pattern' your.pdf
```

or if you want to search in more than just one pdf-file (e.g. in all pdf-files in your folder)

```
pdfgrep 'pattern'  `ls *.pdf`
```

or

```
pdfgrep 'pattern' $(ls *.pdf)
```

Comment: why on earth do you use ls to put filenames in parameters? It's not only slower but also a bad idea to [use `ls` output as the input to other commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425). Just `pdfgrep 'pattern' *.pdf` is enough

Comment: @phuclv Your are wrong. `pdfgrep 'pattern' *.pdf` will not work.

Comment: @f0nzie you're wrong. `$(ls *.pdf)` will be *almost* **exactly** the same as `*.pdf`, only worse because special files are not protected in quotes

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to search for pdf names/properties... or simple strings that are not compressed or encoded then instead of `strings` you can use the below

```
grep -a STRING file.pdf
cat -v file.pdf | grep STRING
```

From `grep --help`:

```
      --binary-files=TYPE   assume that binary files are TYPE;
                            TYPE is 'binary', 'text', or 'without-match'
  -a, --text                equivalent to --binary-files=text
```

and `cat --help`:

```
  -v, --show-nonprinting   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
```

Answer (score 1):

gpdf might be what you need if you're using Gnome! Check [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/open-a-pdf-file-under-linuxfreebsd/) in case you're not using Gnome. It's got a list of CLI pdf viewers. Then you can use `grep` to find some pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean tp not convert it on the disk, you can convert them to `stdout` and then grep it with `pdftotext`. Grepping the pdf without any sort of conversion is not a practical approach since `PDF` is mostly a binary format.

In the directory:

```
ls -1 ./*.pdf | xargs -L1 -I {} pdftotext {}  - | grep "keyword"
```

or in the directory and its subdirectories:

```
tree -fai . | grep -P ".pdf$" | xargs -L1 -I {} pdftotext {}  - | grep "keyword"
```

Also because some `pdf` are scans they need to be OCRed first. I wrote a pretty simple way to search all pdfs that cannot be `grep`ed and OCR them.

I noticed if a `pdf` file doesn't have any font it is usually not searchable. So knowing this we can use `pdffonts`.

First 2 lines of the `pdffonts` are the table header, so when a file is searchable has more than two line output, knowing this we can create:

```
gedit check_pdf_searchable.sh
```

then paste this

```
#!/bin/bash 
#set -vx
if ((`pdffonts "$1" | wc -l` < 3 )); then
echo $1
pypdfocr "$1"
fi
```

then make it executable

```
chmod +x check_pdf_searchable.sh
```

then list all non-searchable pdfs in the directory:

```
ls -1 ./*.pdf | xargs -L1 -I {} ./check_pdf_searchable.sh {}
```

or in the directory and its subdirectories:

```
tree -fai . | grep -P ".pdf$" | xargs -L1 -I {} ./check_pdf_searchable.sh {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
pdfgrep -r --include "*.pdf" -i 'pattern'
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Could you add some explanation on what these options mean? This could also help explain how your approach differs from other answers to this question that also recommend `pdfgrep`.

Answer (score 1):

[ripgrep-all](https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all) (or rga) enables ripgrep functionality on multiple file types, including PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way is

```
grep -rinw "pattern" --include \*.pdf *
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Would you mind adding more explanation to your proposed solution to make it more accessible to the non-expert? For example, your `grep` command-line searches recursively in sub-directories which someone not familiar with `grep` might be unaware of. Also, you included the `-i` flag although ignoring the case may not always be what the user wants. In addition, please explain in what way your approach differs from the asnwer of e.g. @phuclv and others.

Comment: As AdminBee says, the question doesn’t ask for a case-insensitive search or a recursive directory search. The `-n` and `-w` options aren’t justified by the question, either. But, more importantly, this answer tells how to search through text files whose names end with `.pdf` — you’ve missed the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your bashrc:

```bash
LESSOPEN="|/usr/bin/lesspipe %s"; export LESSOPEN
```

Then you can use less:

```
less mypdf.pdf | grep "Hello, World"
```

Check : [https://www.zeuthen.desy.de/~friebel/unix/lesspipe.html](https://www.zeuthen.desy.de/%7Efriebel/unix/lesspipe.html) : to get more about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a GUI you can try [`pdfgrepgui`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfgrepgui/).