# How to search in PDF files recursively?

Tags: pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [grep pdf files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/grep-pdf-files)

With a Linux machine, ex.: an Ubuntu, how can I search for a given word recursively in several PDFs?