# Searching a keyword in a pdf file

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, terminal

I want to search for a specific keyword in a pdf file using linux shell. How I will use the grep command to do that?

Comment: This should help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/how-can-i-grep-in-pdf-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't. PDF is a binary format so you need to convert to text first. Grep can search through the data but there's no reason to assume that a PDF that, when opened in a PDF viewer, has the string `foo` will actually contain `foo` in the original, binary data. It may be written very differently in the source.

A simple solution is to install `pdftotext` and use that. It should be available in your distribution's repositories. On Debian-based systems, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Then, you can search through your PDF file with:

```
pdftotext foo.pdf - | grep keyword
```

Comment: what will be the output of this command? I have used it but no output is shown. If I want to display the found keyword what will I have to do? @terdon♦

Comment: @user3435851 it will be displayed if it was found, just like any other grep. If you get no output, the keyword was not present in the PDF.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: how to search in multiple pdf files? @terdon♦

Comment: @user3435851 use a loop: `for file in *pdf; do pdftotext "$file" | grep pattern"; done`. Please ask a separate question if you are having trouble with this, but make sure to search the site first. All of this has been covered before.

Comment: The command is showing error. Will you please check it? @terdon

Comment: What command? What error? Please post a new question for this. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum and we want to avoid long discussions in the comments. Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works.