# How to run pdftotext ... | grep on many documents?

Tags: debian, pdf, poppler

Code which works with a single document

```
pdftotext *.pdf - | grep therapy
```

You can use `find` as described in the thread [How can I grep in PDF files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27517/16920) but I would like to understand why the above command is not working.

Differential code where `pdfgrep` may add some benefit but still early in development

```
pdftotext *.pdf - | pdfgrep therapy
#Wrong syntax so error
# Usage: pdfgrep [OPTION]... PATTERN FILE...
# Syntax Warning: Invalid Font Weight
# Syntax Warning: Invalid Font Weight
```

I would like to get then a fast way to move to the specific pdf page if there is a good match. 
However, I have not found any evidence that such a feature exists.

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Poppler-utils: pdftotext

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `pdfgrep` directly:

```
pdfgrep -n therapy *.pdf
```

The `-n` option will display the page number of each match.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this;

```
pdfgrep therapy *.pdf
```

or

```
find /tmp -name '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep test {} +
```

eg;

```
user@host $ pdfgrep test *.pdf 
1.pdf:test1
1.pdf:test2
1.pdf:test3
2.pdf:test1
2.pdf:test2
2.pdf:test3
test (copy).pdf:test1
test (copy).pdf:test2
test (copy).pdf:test3


user@host $ find /tmp -name '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep test {} +
/tmp/test (copy).pdf:test1
/tmp/test (copy).pdf:test2
/tmp/test (copy).pdf:test3
/tmp/1.pdf:test1
/tmp/1.pdf:test2
/tmp/1.pdf:test3
/tmp/2.pdf:test1
/tmp/2.pdf:test2
/tmp/2.pdf:test3
```