# Find word or a set of words in a set of pdf files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, pdf

Suppose I have a directory `Note_De_cours` containing 8 other directories, i.e.

```
Semaine_1  Semaine_3  Semaine_5  Semaine_7
Semaine_2  Semaine_4  Semaine_6  Semaine_8
```

Each of those directories contains some pdf files. Is there a command line to search for a word or set of words in each of those pdf in the same time. It is annoying to open a pdf, press `Ctrl + f` and search for the word. I have thought using `grep`, but I am really not an expert. Maybe there some other most optimise ways to do that.

I would like to stay in `Note_De_Cours` and apply `pdfgrep` to see in all the pdf in the same time. I would like the command to tell me which file contains the word or the set of words I want. How can I do that?

**EDIT**

Can I loop through this command : `find elem -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep "baysien optimal" {} +` on `elem`? Something like `for elem in ...; do find elem -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep "baysien optimal" {} +`

I have done `for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do  find Semaine_$i -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep "taux" {} +; done` but it does not output the file where it comes from

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/how-can-i-grep-in-pdf-files

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I grep in PDF files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/how-can-i-grep-in-pdf-files)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson Can I loop through this command : `find elem -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep "baysien optimal" {} +` on `elem`? Something like `for elem in ...; do find elem -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep "baysien optimal" {} +`

Comment: @David You can enter as many source/top directories in `find` as you like: `find Semaine_* -iname '*.pdf' ...`

Comment: Perfecto!! @L.ScottJohnson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```bsh
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8; do  find Semaine_$i -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep "taux" {} +; done
```

if you want to print the name of the file, use -print on find (to print the name after the matches) or -l on grep (to print the name instead of the matches):

```
find Semaine_[1-8] -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep "taux" {} \; -print
```

or

```
find Semaine_[1-8] -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdfgrep -l "taux" {} \;
```

Also, `pdfgrep` has built-in recurse functionality via the `-r` flag, so you could simply do:

`pdfgrep -r -l "taux" Semaine_[1-8]`

Answer (score 0):

You won't get results when you use the grep command directly. Because the applications included in the minimal package of linux can only process files that can be read by vi and nano. (grep, awk etc.) There are many tools and alternatives for special file formats such as PDF.
By installing open source archiving software such as Dspace, you can search and catalog all your PDFs in the browser. By adding modules, you can strengthen PDF operations. Or you can use command line-based applications that convert PDF files to plain text files such as pdftotext. Example search command for pdftotext:

```
pdftotext /file/semaine.pdf - | grep -n -i "Semaine"
```

**-n:** Prints the line numbers.
**-i:** Does not distinguish between uppercase and lowercase letters.

By adding `wc -l` at the end of the command, you can find out how many times the term you're looking for occurs.

You can get more effective results with awk and derivative parameters that you add after pipelines.

As I mentioned above, there is more than one way. I can suggest these two different alternatives.