# Bash, get links from pdf

Tags: command-line, pdf, text

**Os**
ubuntu.

**Need**
to get links or more data (for example binding layer from QuarkXPress application) from pdf to text, in terminal.

**Tried**
*pdftotext*, but seems links are not exported,
*pdfgrep* is the same.

Is there any solution?

Thanks.

Comment: so, uh ... `pdftohtml`? it just works for me, maybe you could share a sample PDF file...

Comment: @Jeff Schaller Yep, I forgot about this. :) Working great.

Comment: Have a look at https://superuser.com/questions/698811/how-to-export-comments-from-a-pdf-file where comments suggest `pdfannotextractor`

Answer (score 4):

You could try and extract the `/URI(...)` PDF directives by hand, maybe after removing compression if any using `pdftk`:

```
pdftk file.pdf output - uncompress | grep -aPo '/URI *\(\K[^)]*'
```

Comment: Thank you, but native pdftohtml is enough.

Comment: @StanislavHosek. OK. I think I misinterpreted your question and that you were wanting to retrieve the list of linked URLs from a PDF file.

Answer (score 2):

Using [pdfx](https://pypi.org/project/pdfx/) and filtering all lines starting with `- http`:

```
pdfx -v file.pdf | sed -n 's/^- \(http\)/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
pdftotext -raw "filename.pdf" && file=`ls -tr | tail -1`; grep -E "https?://.*" "${file}" && rm "${file}"
```

[image: Example of script]

Comment: You should [not parse `ls` ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead), but you can just send output to stdout instead of using a temporary file: `pdftotext -raw "filename.pdf" - | grep ...`   (From `man pdftotext`: `If text-file is ´-', the text is sent to
       stdout.`)

Comment: Nope, it is not working, but thanks.

Comment: pdftotext version 0.71.0 / GNU bash, versão 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) / grep (GNU grep) 3.3.
@pLumo it works either way for me... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pdftohtml and then use lynx to pull the links from the html.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check if your pdf is compressed or not, see:

[How to know if a PDF file is compressed or not and to (un)compress it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17663/how-to-know-if-a-pdf-file-is-compressed-or-not-and-to-uncompress-it)

If it's compressed, you need to uncompress it.

Then, you can extract links using `grep` and `sed`:

```
strings uncompressed.pdf | grep -Eo '/URI \(.*\)' | sed 's/^\/URI (//g; s/)$//g'
```